# How to find non english language and its data in a table of sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, chinese-locale, non-english

I have a Sql Server table loaded with data from multiple countries. Say Japanese, Thai, Urdu, Portuguese, Spanish and many more which i didn't identify.

How to identify the language and its relevant data  from that table ?

sample:

```
colid  |  colname
1      |  stackoverflow
2      |  龍梅子, 老貓
```

i need a query to produce :

```
stackoverflow, english
龍梅子, 老貓 , chinese
```

is this possible to get ?

Comment: Many languages are written using the same alphabet. It's going to be very hard to tell them apart based only on the letters used. Without context, even google are having a hard time telling single words.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, you are right! But it should be possible to find the unicode-family at least...

Comment: Hi, I was puzzeling around with finding the correct unicode for the characters in use and have re-done my answer. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(100)=N'龍梅子, 老貓';
SELECT UNICODE(Left(@str,1))
```

The result is `40845`

A google search on `unicode 40845` [brought me here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9f8d/index.htm).

It seems to be the *dragon* or *emperor* from chinese character set

Some more information upon [unicode character ranges](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php)

The given code points to *CJK Unified Ideographs*

### UPDATE

In order to use this:

You will either have to

- get a local copy of a full list into your database and do a look-up. Something like from here: http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html
- or create a range table (much smaller!) like in the link given (http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php)
- or do some kind of web lookup...

Comment: Its helpful. but im getting below from table.0x949f
0x8d9f
0x4a9f
0x139f
0xd29e
0xd19e
0xce9e
0xc49e
where i cant identify in the Unicode Characters Ranges URL. Please suggest

Comment: @Sudheerkrishna, Is this issue solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: yes.. its really useful in terms of me. But there are lot more things in that chart where i need to check more languages. Anyway, thanks for your turn around.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, what if the languages use the same alphabet, or even worse share the same words? You obviously wouldn't want to ask an internet ai-based program to decide.

You should add a column language_id, have a table for the languages and hope that it's not too many entries to update.